# Pass an array through a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to keep it simple here.

I have some data. It contains a list of objects we'll call `items`. I loop through the `items`, and pass various properties to a component like so:

```
  render: function(){
    var itemList = [];

    items.forEach(function(item){
      itemList.push(<Component name={item.name} tags={item.tags} />)
    })
    return(
      <ul id="item-list">
        {itemList}
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

So the issue here is that `item.tags` is an array. From within my component, I am just doing something simple like display the name and then loop through the tags to display them:

```
  render: function(){
    var tags = [];

    this.props.tags.forEach(function(tag){
      tags.push( <li>{tag}</li> />)
    })
    return(
      <li>
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <ul>
          {tags}
        </ul>
      </li>
    )
  }
```

From within the component, tags is undefined.

What do I do/am I doing wrong, because I am very new to React. Thanks!

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't suggest any particular problem. Can you show us your actual, complete code instead, and/or reproduce the problem in a fiddle (use the [React Base Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/))?

Answer (score 3):

May need more code to be helpful.

If your `Component` class is being given a `tags` prop, `this.props.tags` will always be a reference to it.

Is there any chance you are doing something funny, such as `cloneWithProps`, or using a dynamic `<Component/>` class?

You might try passing in `item` as a `prop`, and pull out the tags in the component.

```
<Component item={item}/>
```

That will let you see easier why `tags` isn't available.